# Mysql Trigger comes up with error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this trigger which should do this :

BEFORE a new entry is created in the entry log table , it will take the driver_id from that table , put it into the if statement and then set the allowed field from the new entry to either Y or No based on the outcome .

```
    create trigger xxx before insert on entrylog for each row
if  exists (select *
              from driver
              join card_driver
                on driver.id = card_driver.driver_id
              join card
                on card_driver.card_id = card.id
             where driver.id = new.driver_id) then
    set new.allowed = 'Y';
end if
```

The only problem is that it dosent work . I keep getting this error if I try an put it into phpmyadmin :

```
    Error

SQL query: Documentation

CREATE trigger allowedupdate before INSERT ON entrylog
FOR each
ROW
IF EXISTS (

SELECT *
FROM driver
JOIN card_driver ON driver.id = card_driver.driver_id
JOIN card ON card_driver.card_id = card.id
WHERE driver.id = new.driver_id
)
THEN
SET new.allowed = 'Y';

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9
```

The if statement is taken from this and should produce the same outcome (just not echoing messages)

```
$sql ="SELECT *
  FROM driver AS d 
INNER
  JOIN card_driver AS cd
    ON cd.driver_id = d.id
INNER
  JOIN card AS c
    ON c.id = cd.card_id     
 WHERE d.ID = $id";
mysql_select_db('damp');
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
switch($row['state_id'])
{
case "1":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"green\">Authorisation Granted!</font></strong>";
   break; // This should be a Y , the rest are N
case "2":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">Your card has expired and authorisation is denied</font></strong>";
   break;
case "3":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">Your card has been cancelled and authorisation is denied</font></strong>";
   break;
default:
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">The Card ID does not exist</font></strong>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very subtle problem, but you are missing the final `end if`.  It is there, but the semicolon ends the trigger definition.  This is why MySQL has the `delimiter` keyword.

The trigger definition should look like:

```
delimiter $$
create trigger xxx before insert on entrylog for each row
begin
    if  exists (select *
                  from driver
                  join card_driver
                    on driver.id = card_driver.driver_id
                  join card
                    on card_driver.card_id = card.id
                 where driver.id = new.driver_id) then
        set new.allowed = 'Y';
    end if;
end;$$
delimiter ;
```

I also added the `begin/end`.  Although not strictly necessary, I always use them.  And, you would have gotten a compile time error if your original statement had them.

Comment: As per my knowledge, `begin` - `end` block is required only when number of delimited statements are more than `1`(one). In the query posting `set ..` is stmt 1 and `end if` is 2. So we need a 2nd semicolon and hence a `begin` - `end` block.

Comment: @Ravinder . . . The original trigger consists of one statement, which is an `if` statement.  The definition of the trigger ends at the semicolon on the `set` statement.  The `begin`/`end` block is not needed, but I would always include it.  Such a block can contain one statement.

Comment: That is true. It is always good to include begin-end block, even for a single executable statement. But `set new.allowed=if( !exists(...), 'Y', new.allowed );` is a simple solution, unless OP is going to add more statements to the body.

Comment: so now iv got this error : #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Comment: @Lazis002 . . . Drop the trigger and recreate it.

Comment: what do you mean by dropping the trigger

Comment: @Lazis002 . . . You might have another trigger defined on the table.  Alterntiavely, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-trigger.html.